# Laravel Relationship Suggestion

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent, polymorphism

I have a concept for a relationship in my mind, but I am not really sure how I should accomplish it. I am rebuilding a site and want to make sure my relationships this time around are proper and allow for scaling.

Here is the concept: I have different types of mentions. When you are adding a comment, a blog post, or a message board post, you can mention multiple things (i.e. Type '#' and type, then select what you want to mention). The complexity is that you can mention users, actors, movies, or tv shows.

I like the idea of having everything in one "mentions" table as a polymorphic. But because I have multiple models on both sides, I am not sure if a dual polymorphic table is possible and if it would be a nightmare to work with. Or, should I do do individual many to many tables for each place mentions can occur (i.e. "blog_mentions", "message_board_mentions", ...) and have the "what was mentioned" as the only polymorphic component in each table?

Would love to hear everyone's thoughts. Thanks!